# Call subroutine of a userForm within another userForm with Application.Run

Tags: excel, vba

I try to create a UserForm called "UtilTextBox" which will receive text input from the user. The result will be send back to the userForm which created the "UtilTextBox".
The "UtilTextBox" should be reusable for any future UserForm.

I've tried to pass the name of the outgoing UserForm to the TextBox Userform and call it with Application.Run, when the user clicks the submit button.

Subroutine within first UserForm called "TextEditor"

```vb
Private Sub Between1Edit_Click()
    UtilTextBox.Show
    UtilTextBox.callback = "TextEditor.GetResult"
End Sub
```

Code of the "UtilTextBox"

```vb
Public callback As String


Private Sub Send_Click()
    Application.Run callback, TextBox.text
End Sub
```

Subroutine of first UserForm which will receive the text input

```vb
Public Sub GetResult(result As String)
    MsgBox result
End Sub
```

Both UserForms are within the same workbook by the way.

I've expected that the text send by the user gets passed and printed out by MsgBox.

Instead of this i received run-time error '1004': Cannot run the macro.
Isn't it possible to call public subs from an UserForm with Application.Run?

Comment: No, it isn't. You could pass the relevant form as an Object, then use `CallByName` instead.

Comment: Can you not just have a public variable in a module which is updated by the first form and when the second form is activated, it takes the value from this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the only method is CallByName:

Code from TextEditor

```
Private Sub Between1Edit_Click()
    UtilTextBox.callback = "GetResult"
    Set UtilTextBox.frm = Me
    UtilTextBox.Show
End Sub

Public Sub GetResult(result As String)
    MsgBox result
End Sub
```

Code from UtilTextBox

```
Public callback     As String
Public frm          As Object

Private Sub Send_Click()
    CallByName Me.frm, Me.callback, VbMethod, Me.TextBox.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the lines

```
Private Sub Between1Edit_Click()
    UtilTextBox.callback = "TextEditor.GetResult"
    UtilTextBox.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: this change does nothing at all, UtilTextBox isnt modal so switching the lines makes no difference